# Tkinter layout_label width changed by the one beneath

Tags: tkinter, layout

```py
lbl_hour = Label(root, text='hour', width=5).grid(row=1, column=0)
lbl_minute = Label(root, text='minute', width=5).grid(row=1, column=2)
lbl_second = Label(root, text='second', width=5).grid(row=1, column=4)

lbl = Label(root, bg='#F0F8FF', fg='#B22222', font=('arial', 20), padx=50, pady=10)
```

If I understand correctly, the width of those 3 labels hour/minute/second should be 5 as the pre-set, but not sure why it would be affected by the label beneath it? please refer to the snapshot that the time label could always change the width of the label above it, how to fix this? thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If the clock is in the same column as the hour label, then it is expected result.

Comment: i guess i would have to try another way to illustrate them, thanks!